# How to include a .launch file on a remote machine from a .launch file?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, include, network, remote

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using openni_launch drivers for the Kinect on my robot. I am running roscore on a separate computer, my laptop. I have added a line reading  to the openni.launch file on the robot computer so I can access the various image topics such as /camera/rgb/image_color from my laptop.

As it is, I can run the launch file on my laptop which creates the connection to the robot, and THEN I have to go over to the robot computer and launch openni.launch to start the Kinect drivers. This works fine, but it is inconvenient. I want to be able to start the Kinect drivers (execute the openni.launch file on the robot computer) from the launch file on my laptop.

I am wondering if there is a way to add an  tag to the launch file on my laptop that will run the openni.launch file on the robot.

Naturally, I looked at the  documentation at http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/include already, but there doesn't seem to be anything about including a file on another machine. That's why I thought I would check here.

Thanks very much for reading, and hope you can help!

-Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41413/how-to-include-a-.launch-file-on-a-remote-machine-from-a-.launch-file?/) by [cdleveille](https://answers.ros.org/users/3033/cdleveille/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-08-14

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like it's undocumented, and it even gives a warning if you try to use it, but! You can, in fuerte, at least, add a "machine" attribute to an "include" tag in a launchfile and get it to launch everything in that included launchfile to come up on another machine.

See here for setting up machine tags: http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/machine

And then just simply do (with appropriate values) something like:

```
<launch>
  <machine name="other-pc" address="192.168.13.37" env-loader="/opt/ros/fuerte/env.sh"/>
  <include file="/path/to/file/on/local/machine.launch" machine="other-pc"/>
</launch>
```

It looks like what this is doing is actually reading a launchfile on the local machine, and then bringing up its nodes on the other machine!

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on 2012-09-04**:
I have tried that with openni.launch, but it still launches nodes on local machine.

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-09-05**:
Maybe it only works one level deep. This is an undocumented feature, but definitely something that I think should be added to the hydro roslaunch SIG: http://www.ros.org/wiki/hydro/Planning/roslaunch

**Comment by [amrivera](https://answers.ros.org/users/3700/amrivera/) on 2013-03-22**:
I tried it in ROS Electric, but had no luck.
WARNING: [path/to/MASTER/pc/name.launch] unknown  attribute 'machine'

I need to launch a node in a ClientPC with files living in the ClientPC too. Currently it attempts to read files in MASTERPC which also has them, but no luck either. Ideas?

**Comment by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on 2013-08-15**:
On hydro this results in error:
WARNING: [...launch] unknown  attribute 'machine'

**Comment by [Girmi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29032/girmi/) on 2017-01-16**:
This isn't working on ROS Kinetic either, resulting in a warning and the nodes being launched on the local PC.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If anyone is still looking for an answer, I think currently the most elegant solution is:

```
<launch>
        <include file="local_nodes.launch" />

        <group>
            <machine name="remote_machine" address="1.2.3.4" default="true" />
            <include file="remote_nodes.launch" />
        </group>
</launch>
```

Tested with ROS Kinectic on Ubuntu 16.04.

Edit:
Apparently the machine tag doesn't apply to a specific group, but to any nodes/includes that come after it. So the order in which the tags are defined is important!

---

Originally posted by [Girmi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29032/girmi/) with karma: 111 on 2017-01-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Girmi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29032/girmi/) on 2017-02-06**:
Apparently the machine tag doesn't apply to a specific group, but to any nodes/includes that come after it. So the order in which the tags are defined is important!

**Comment by [philwall3](https://answers.ros.org/users/32152/philwall3/) on 2018-02-22**:
Also the default="true" tag is needed to work properly. After adding that, it is finally working for me. Thanks!

**Comment by [Girmi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29032/girmi/) on 2018-02-22**:
Do you mean the defailt="true" attribute of the  element (which is present in my example)? Or is an additional attribute needed somewhere?

**Comment by [philwall3](https://answers.ros.org/users/32152/philwall3/) on 2018-02-22**:
Yes I mean in the machine element like shown in your example. I was missing it at first and it was not opening the ssh connection to the remote machine, but instead just starting the launch file on the local machine.

**Comment by [MikeWrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/46798/mikewrock/) on 2019-11-19**:
It seems to me like any file included via the file="" tag will be read locally but launched remotely, as in remote_nodes.launch must exist locally, but will launch the nodes mentioned within remotely. Can anyone else confirm this behaviour?

**Comment by [Girmi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29032/girmi/) on 2019-11-20**:
This is indeed the case. The same goes for the fact that any nodes you want to launch remotely, have to be installed locally as well.

**Comment by [Hemanth](https://answers.ros.org/users/39363/hemanth/) on 2019-11-21**:
I was able to launch a node remotely and that node was not installed locally. However, I am observing a problem with launching remote launch files. The ROS path of the local system is being checked for the package that contains the launch file and I recieved the ResourceNotFound error.

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2021-07-13**:
does anyone has solved this issue. cas i'm also facing same issue and unable to solve it.

**Comment by [MikeWrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/46798/mikewrock/) on 2021-07-13**:
The solution I've used is to execute a command over SSH using a bash script called from a launch file. See my answer below